# How can i have custom (Computed) property in objectmapper?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, objectmapper

I am using Objectmapper and Realm for my project.

I have an object like following

```
class File
{
  dynamic var name
  dynamic var folder
  dynamic var path // This is not coming from JSON // this should be combination of both name+folder
}
```

I thought of writing a computed property to achieve this but Realm does not support computed properties as primary key.

But I should use this as primary key. Is there any way I can manipulate to add that value after coming from server response.

Note: I am using AlamofireObjectMapper.

I am using the following method which parses the server response and gives me the model object.

```
 Alamofire.request(router).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<T>) in
{
  let myModel = response.result.value // Parsed object
===== What can i do here to achieve my requirement=====
}
```

Comment: How does your model class looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider having some kind of `id` as the primary key and not computing it from other properties (what happens if they are empty or the computation goes wrong? You'd be left without a valid primary key).

However, if you really need to, you could try

```
let realm = try Realm()
try realm.write {
      items.forEach({ (item) in
          item.path = item.name + item.folder
      }
      realm.add(items, update: true)
}
```

and don't forget to define `path` as the primary key in the `File` class:

```
class File
{
    dynamic var name
    dynamic var folder
    dynamic var path // This is not coming from JSON // this should be combination of both name+folder

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "path"
    }
}
```